# How to insert '$' sign infront of textvariable in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I created an ATM using tkinter
which displays the current balance while clicking the balance button
and it adds the money deposited and withdrawed which are in different classes which gets added or subtracted from the current balance which is set 0 and the balance

gets stored in

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.shared_data={'Balance':tk.IntVar()}
```

And the remaining balance gets displayed on the screen

```
class BalancePage(tk.Frame):
        global current_balance
        controller.shared_data['Balance'].set(current_balance)
    
        balance_label=tk.Label(self,textvariable=controller.shared_data['Balance'],font=('orbitron',13),fg='white',bg='#3d3d5c',anchor='w')
        balance_label.pack(fill='x')
```

I just want to display a '$' sign in front of the Amount (i.e is 0 and want $0) displayed plz help

[image]

```
#WithdrawPage
class WithdrawPage(tk.Frame):
        def withdraw(amount):
            global current_balance
            if amount>current_balance:
                messagebox.showwarning('WARNING','Not sufficient funds!')
            else:
                current_balance -= amount
                controller.shared_data['Balance'].set(current_balance)
                controller.show_frame('MenuPage')
#DepositPage
class DepositPage(tk.Frame):
        def deposit_cash():
            global current_balance
            current_balance += int(cash.get())
            controller.shared_data['Balance'].set(current_balance)
            controller.show_frame('MenuPage')
            cash.set('')
```

Comment: where exactly do u want to insert `$` ?

Comment: @Cool Cloud in front of it like $0

Comment: Set up another `StringVar` for the `textvariable` of `balance_label`: `balance_label = tk.Label(..., textvariable=balance_var,...)`.  Then set up `trace()` on `self.shared_data['Balance']` and update `balance_var` in the trace callback: `balance_var.set('$'+str(shared_data['Balance'].get()))`.

Comment: @acw1668 may you plz type the code and show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up another `StringVar` for the `textvariable` of `balance_label`:

```
balance_label = tk.Label(..., textvariable=self.balance_var,...)
```

Then set up `trace()` on `controller.shared_data['Balance']` and update `self.balance_var` in the trace callback:

```
self.balance_var.set('$'+str(self.controller.shared_data['Balance'].get()))
```

As I don't have full picture of your code, below is the suggested changes on your code:

```
class BalancePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kw):
        ...
        self.controller = controller

        self.balance_var = tk.StringVar()
        controller.shared_data['Balance'].trace('w', self.on_balance_changed)

        balance_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.balance_var, font=('orbitron',13),
                                 fg='white', bg='#3d3d5c', anchor='w')
        balance_label.pack(fill='x')
        ...

    def on_balance_changed(self, *args):
        self.balance_var.set('$'+str(self.controller.shared_data['Balance'].get()))
```

Comment: Blank Screen is Appearing

Comment: yes i didnt do it because blank screen appeared because of it

Comment: You put the `def on_balance_change()` function in wrong place.  I have updated your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this example to achieve what you to do by concatenating the `$` with the final result

```
print ("$"+ current_balance)
```

or this

```
print ("$", current_balance)
```

Comment: but the current_balance is getting displayed by this

        balance_label=tk.Label(self,textvariable=controller.shared_data['Balance'],font=('orbitron',13),fg='white',bg='#3d3d5c',anchor='w')
        balance_label.pack(fill='x')

Comment: So which one is the textvariable. Is it `cash.get()`

Comment: this is`textvariable=controller.shared_data['Balance']`
`cash.get()`returns the input from user and adds it up in current_balance as int

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `balance_label` text variable like this:

```
balance_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable="$"+controller.shared_data['Balance'], font=('orbitron', 13), fg='white', bg='#3d3d5c', anchor='w')
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "IntVar") to str` will be raised by your code.